# JS Prototype Not Working

Tags: javascript

Could someone take a look at this and help me to understand why the prototype.placing is not console logging? Thank you for your help:

```
(function() {
   function Rider(name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.show = function(showName) {
           console.log(this.name + " rode in the " + showName);
       };
   }

    var riderOne = new Rider("Billy Bobb");
    riderOne.show("Summer Show");

    Rider.prototype.placing = function(place) {
        console.log(this.rider + " ended up in " + place + " at " +
                this.showName);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Where are you calling it? (From the looks of it, no where)

Comment: Yeah that is where I am stuck with this. I could not get it to come up in the console so I figured that I must have been not using this right. Where/how would I call this so that it would show up in the console?

Comment: well you have to call it somewhere after you define it..

Comment: You use your object's properties inconsistantly (`this.name`, `this.rider`, never setting `this.showName`)

Comment: @peretrai1 riderOne won't show up for use in the console because you've scoped it to a function if that is what you mean...

Comment: If this is not too hard, could someone add an answer with how to call the placing so I can try and then give credit to? I am able to get the first console to work correctly but not the console log for the prototype. I have a feeling I understand now that I need to call it but need to have an answer here so I can assign correct answer to, if that makes sense? Thank you all for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look here, it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/D3BKz/1/

code:

```
(function() {
   function Rider(name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.showName = "";
       this.show = function(showName) {
           this.showName = showName;
           console.log(this.name + " rode in the " + showName);
       };
   }
    Rider.prototype.placing = function(place) {
        console.log(this.name + " ended up in " + place + " at " +
                this.showName);
    }
    var riderOne = new Rider("Billy Bobb");
    riderOne.show("Summer Show");
    riderOne.placing("1st");

})();
```

I've changed this:

```
Rider.prototype.placing = function(place) {
    console.log(this.rider+ " ended up in " + place + " at " +
            this.showName);
}
```

to this:

```
Rider.prototype.placing = function(place) {
    console.log(this.name + " ended up in " + place + " at " +
            this.showName);
}
```

and then I used

```
riderOne.placing("1st");
```

and here is the console output:

```
Billy Bobb rode in the Summer Show
Billy Bobb ended up in 1st at Summer Show
```

---

EDIT:

as someone pointed out, showName is never defined inside your Rider class. I've updated the code, adding the showName property to the class.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I did this as well about the same time you were doing the fiddle. The last part I am stuck on to get the gist of this is how do I get the show name to not be undefined? Is there part of the object Rider that I need to change?

Comment: @pertrai1 I've updated my code and I've added the showName part, have a look :)

Comment: Yes this worked great. Thank you for taking the time again as I was able to work side by side with the changes and trying to figure out what needed to be changed also. Being able to see these changes helped me to learn more about using prototype.